# House numbers are shown at zoom level 18. Is it possible to get it earlier?

Tags: here-api

At zoom-level 18 house numbers are shown, and at zoom level 15 the first buildings are shown.

Is it possible to specify that the house numbers and buildings should be shown ealier ? Ie. at a higher zoom level.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can only be accomplished with a custom map scheme. Also, performance of loading and rendering the house numbers at a lower zoom level will compromise rendering performance.